# Number-Theory Books to read before studying Analytic Number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

S.E friends,

Due to my genuine interest to Goldbach's conjecture, I decided to self-study the subject of additive number theory on this upcoming Fall.  Before jumping to such fascinating field of mathematics, I decided to self-study "introductory" number theory as I never took a number-theory course in past.  While browsing through websites and libraries, I found books like Ireland/Rosen, Apostol, Nathanson,Hardy/Wright, Sierpinski, and Niven/Zuckerman/Montogomery.  I really like them but I am not sure what book would be best for my plan to study additive number theory.  Ireland/Rosen looks like it emphasizes algebraic aspect and assumes familiarity with elementary number theory from readers, Hardy/Wright and Apostol looks like an introduction to analytic number theory (which I am doubting if it is better idea to just start with additive number theory), etc.  Currently, I fear that choosing wrong book might kill my curiosity to the number theory.

What books do you recommend to prepare for analytic number theory?

Comment: If you want the basics, a quick google search led me to this link:
http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/An-Introductory-in-Elementary-Number-Theory.pdf
Everything up to chapter 4 seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: There is no such thing as the best book, there is only the best book *for you*, and that is something no one can know until after the fact. Having said that, I'd say Apostol, Hardy/Wright, and Niven/Zuckerman/Montgomery, the ones I'm most familiar with from your list, are all excellent choices.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
Elementary number theory by David Burton.
Number theory by Titu Andreescu are good for starters.
Then you can move on to more advance books.

Comment: Which one of these two do you think is better for mathematical olympiads?